# Merging two rows mysql

Tags: mysql

Was wondering if you guys could help me, I'm trying to merge two rows into one for this table I have.

Currently my data is like this

```
    Item                Descr       Total       Proj
    Fuse                abc         0           Inventory
    Fuse - Labor        def         19415       Inventory
    Jumper              ghi         0           Inventory
    Jumper - Labor      jkl         434.14      Inventory
```

What I was hoping to do was to combine rows for the Desc column. I was able to do it but its not yet entirely correct, I wanted to get the row with the totals value, with the current query I used it only got the rows with 0 total value

```
    SELECT 

    SUBSTRING_INDEX(Item, ' - ', 1) as lineItem,
    GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT Descr SEPARATOR '\n\n') as description,
    Total,
    Project

    FROM table1 
    WHERE deleted = 0
    AND Proj = "Inventory"

    GROUP BY SUBSTRING_INDEX(Item, ' - ', 1)
```

The output of the query I tried is this:

```
    Item        Descr       Total       Proj
    Fuse        abc         0           Inventory

                def
    Jumper      ghi         0           Inventory

                jkl
```

What I was hoping to get was like this output:

```
    Item        Descr       Total       Proj
    Fuse        abc         19415       Inventory

                def
    Jumper      ghi         434.14      Inventory

                jkl
```

How should I adjust my query to get the output above? Thank you

Comment: `sum(Total)` ? Are you actually using MySQL? I am unsure how the query is not failing because you are not grouping by `Total` or `Proj`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just taking the sum of the total should get you close to the output you want:

```
SELECT 
    SUBSTRING_INDEX(Item, ' - ', 1) AS lineItem,
    GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT Descr SEPARATOR '\n\n') AS description,
    SUM(Total) AS Total,
    Project
FROM table1 
WHERE deleted = 0 AND Project = 'Inventory'
GROUP BY
    SUBSTRING_INDEX(Item, ' - ', 1),
    Project;
```

Note that we also have to group by the project.

Comment: i think my comment yesterday was deleted but just wanted to say this worked thank you

Answer (score 0):

I'm surprised your query works at all (depends on your database variant of SQL I guess), because you don't have any aggregation function around `Total`.  It seems to interpret this by just returning the first value of `Total` within each group, rather than (as I think it should) returning an error.

Just use `sum(Total)` instead of `Total` in the `SELECT` and I think it will probably work.

BTW the column names in your table are different from the query (`Project` v `Proj`) but I presume this is just a typo.